# Browsers change font weight in H tags

Tags: css, browser, fonts

I'm hosting my own fonts, but I've also created a fiddle linking to Google fonts and the problem remains.

All browsers change the weight of the font in the H tags.

I find this a bit disconcerting particularly when in my case I'm specifying the font file that should be used.

If for example I set, both `<h3>` and `<p>`, with `font-family: 'robotoregular';` and use the same exact font-size in both cases, I would expect the same exact result in both of them. Instead, what the browsers produce is a bold version of the font in the `<h3>`, and the only way to set it right is to specify the font-weight, which shouldn't be necessary if I'm already indicating a specific font file.

Is this behavior to be expected, and why does this happen?
Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fchmv7ew/)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'robotoregular';
  src: local('robotoregular'), url('../fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
  local('robotoregular'), url('../fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

p {
  font-family: 'robotoregular';
  font-size: 27px;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'robotoregular';
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: normal; /*IF NOT INCLUDED, THE BROWSER WILL MAKE IT BOLD*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers apply [a wide variety of defaults](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp). Headers get `font-weight: bold`, among other things (like margins).

If you want complete, total control, consider [a reset stylesheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reset_style_sheet).